# Is this an R-balanced map if R is not commutative?

Tags: tensor-products

The following is a (not completely identical) version of an example that appears on page 370 of Dummit and Foote.

Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative ring), let $I$ be a two-sided ideal in $R$, and let $N$ be a left $R$-module.  Then $R/I$ is a right $R$-module (presumably the action is given by the natural projection of $R$ onto $R/I$).  Define $IN$ to be the submodule of all finite sums of the form $\sum a_{i}n_{i}$ where $a_{i}\in I$ and $n_{i}\in N$.  Define a map from $(R/I)\times N$ to $N/IN$ by $(r+I,n)\rightarrow (rn+IN)$.

This doesn't appear to be an R-balanced map in general if R is not commutative since $((r+I)r^{'},n)=(rr^{'}+I,n)\rightarrow (rr^{'})n+IN$ and $(rr^{'})n+IN \neq (r^{'}r)n+IN$ in general.  The book claims this is ("easily checked to be") R-balanced.  Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: $R$-balanced just means that $\varphi((r+I)r',n) = \varphi(r+I, r'n)$, which is true in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us write $f:R/I\times N\to N/IN$ for your map.  For $f$ to be balanced, it needs to satisfy $f((r+I)r',n)=f(r+I,r'n)$.  You have correctly computed $f((r+I)r',n)$ to be $(rr')n+IN$.  But $f(r+I,r'n)$ is $r(r'n)+IN$, not $(r'r)n+IN$ as you said.  Thus $$f((r+I)r',n)=(rr')n+IN=r(r'n)+IN=f(r+I,r'n),$$ as desired.